# Contar resultados sql em tabela tendo ou não valores

Tags: mysql, loop

Eu tenho uma tabela `subcategorias` e tenho uma outra `anuncios`, onde nesta possui o id da subcategoria. Eu preciso buscar todas as subcategorias e retornar junto, por subcategoria, a quantidade de anúncios que esta possui, o problema é que eu já estou gerando as subcategorias com um outro loop de outra tabela. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
SELECT * from `subcategorias`
LEFT JOIN `anuncios` ON `subcategorias`.`id_subcategoria` = `anuncios`.`id_anuncio`
WHERE `anuncios`.`status` = 1;
```

Então, basicamente, eu tenho que listar todas as subcategorias, e junto, fazer um count de quantos anúncios ativos cada uma possui para depois eu jogar este loop na página

Comment: se anuncio possui o id da subcategoria, porque não faz ON subcategoria.id = anuncios.id_subcategoria ?

Comment: Porque as subcategorias são geradas dinamicamente através da página de categorias. Pelo ID da  categoria, que é formado o loop com o menu de subcategorias. Neste menu são listados os nomes das subcategorias e a quantidade de anúncios que cada uma possui, contudo, mesmo que a subcategoria não contenha anúncio, o loop deve continuar sendo executado para trazer todas as subcategorias mas até o momento, o que eu fiz foi trazer apenas as subcategorias que contêm anúncios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é unir os resultados de categorias que não tem nenhum anúncio ativo com a contagem de categorias que tem anúncios ativos com essa *query*:

```
select
subcategoria.nome,
coalesce(count(anuncios.id)) as quantidade
from subcategoria
left join anuncios on anuncios.id_subcategoria = subcategoria.id
where anuncios.status = 1
group by subcategoria.nome
union
select nome, '0' as quantidade from subcategoria
where subcategoria.id not in (select id_subcategoria from anuncios where status = 1)
order by nome
```

Veja esse [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ea799/11).

Comment: Laércio, perfeito. Deu certo aqui, só agora vou ver como repassar para o Laravel mas está buscando a quantidade de anúncios por subcategoria. Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um `COUNT(anuncios.*)` AS qtd na sua query e um `GROUP BY` subcategoria.id_subcategoria.
Porém observando assim parece estar errado o relacionamento do JOIN, mas como a pergunta não é essa a Resposta acima resolve, ficando assim:

```
    SELECT  
    s.*,
    count(*) as qtd
FROM subcategorias s
LEFT JOIN anuncios a
ON a.id_subcategoria = s.id_subcategoria
GROUP BY s.id_subcategoria
```

Comment: arllondias, obrigado pela ajuda mas tentei aqui e retornou a mesma coisa. Retorna apenas os resultados referentes aos anúncios, e o importante é retorna as subcategorias e, se houver anúncios, a quantidade deles.

Comment: tenho as mesmas tabelas aqui pra teste e funcionam, tente mudar a referencia do seu join que acho que está errado deixando como a resposta, irei editar

Answer (score 0):

Tentei editar aqui para poder pegar por categoria solicitada mas a quantidade retornada é sempre 1 registro

editei aqui para poder pegar a categoria solicitada mas aí a quantidade sempre informa como tendo um registro

```
SELECT s.*, 
COUNT(*) AS qtd 
FROM subcategorias s 
JOIN categorias c 
ON c.id_categoria = s.id_categoria 
LEFT JOIN anuncios a 
ON a.id_subcategoria = s.id_subcategoria 
WHERE s.id_categoria = 6 
GROUP BY s.id_subcategoria
```